Passing EN-55032 (Class B) Conducted Emission Test with POE+ Mode (Design based on AG5724-LPB Silvertel)
I'm trying to pass Conducted Emission test for a product that I worked on that has Silvertel's AG5724-LPB.
Here is how the setup looks inside the lab:

Note 1: the red wire is a connection to CHASSIS ground (but it's not ideal - measuring the resistance between RJ-45 Chassis and the wall gives 0.2 ohm).
Note 2: We added a coupling clamp but it didn't help in getting rid of the peaks.
Note 3: I added an Ethernet extender in order for the cable to pass through the clamp. (I'm not sure if the extender is compatible with 1 GbE interface). I'm considering making a re-test with a longer direct cable with the shield exposed without this extender.
Currently, measuring the PWR+DATA line between DUT and PSE, gives the following result in CE test:

Note: PWR+DATA Ethernet cable is S-STP (Shielded Shielded Twisted Pair) CAT-7 that is shielded, and the cable is exposed at some point were the shield is connected to the chamber GND through 10-ohm resistors.
After following Silvertel's POE EMI Considerations, I figured out that my schematic lacks certain factors:

470uF Electrolytic Capacitor at the POE Module's output.
C2-C2 Capacitors between VIN+, VIN- and GND.

Also, the test setup was lacking ISN (Impedance Stabilization Network), and Silvertel suggested TESEQ CDN T8 , where the lab has Fischer, Universal Telecom, ISN F-071115-1057-1. (I still didn't check the LAB's ISN spec in order to see if it deals with the frequency range that I have peaks at).
Note: the lab claims that since the cables are shielded, the ISN was not added to the setup. but I still want to do a re-test with un-shielded cables + ISN since I believe the ISN will still get rid of the problematic frequencies even if the cable's quality will be lower.
The Diagram below shows how the ISN must be connected (Between DUT and PSE's PWR+DATA input):

The Question:
Given the described setup and the Silvertel suggestion to add the ISN, what else can I add to the schematic to get rid of the problematic frequencies?
Seems like the first peak is around 400 Khz, the second is around 700 Khz - 750 Khz, and then there seems to be some pattern.

It kind of does look like harmonics. First thing to check would be the the switch regulator frequency, but even if that's something different it's still the major suspect. We will need schematics + PCB layout to assist. Although, the setup looks a bit on the rat's nest side of things, compared to what I'm used at seeing at labs. All those stray wires shouldn't be there.
